# try/catch/finally , How to prevent finally when i have return in my catch?

Tags: c#

I have this code and i want to prevent finally execution

```
        try
        {
            throw new Exception("Try Error!!!");
        }
        catch(Exception exp)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(exp.Message);
            Console.ReadLine();
            if(exp.Message == "Try Error!!!")
                return;
        }
        finally
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Finally...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

But return doesn't work.

Comment: Your code shows several problems: First, it looks like you are using exceptions to control execution flow, which is not recommended. Throwing an exception to jump to the `catch` block is no different from using `goto`. Next, you are throwing a `System.Exception`, and catching a `System.Exception`, and then checking its message to determine its type. If you have an OOP language like C#, you can at least create several custom Exception classes and use multiple `catch` blocks to distinguish them. Catching all exceptions is wrong.

Comment: @LightWing It dont make any sense please specify in the question where you want it and also note that this is agaisnt oops. If you still want to do it then why you should have finally???

Answer (score 12, accepted):

the finally doesn't run only in following three conditions  :

1. The System.exit() is called from the `try` or `catch` block.
2. There is an infinite loop inside the try block.
3. The system crashes or power loss while executing the try block.

for all other conditions .... the finally is always executed... having a boolean variable to control the execution of finally code is a clever approach... go for it...

Comment: Also, finally blocks are not guaranteed to run if the runtime is shutting down (e.g. in the event of a stack overflow exception thrown by the runtime or an unhandled exception on the finalizer thread).

Comment: @aProgrammer, What if System.exit() statement is executed from catch block?

try
{
    throw new Exception();
}
catch
{
    System.exit();
}
finally
{
    Console.WriteLine("Should I Print?");
}

Comment: @HirenKagrana In that case finally block won't execute if there is an exception.

Answer (score 9):

That's the point of finally - it always runs.

try this:

```
bool runfinally = true;
try {
  throw new Exception("test");
} catch {
  runfinally = false;
} finally {
  if(runfinally) {
     // do stuff.
  }
}
```

Comment: ps - Groo's comment above is important - I've explained how to do what you think you want to do.  In fact, chances are that you don't want to do that ;)

Answer (score 3):

Why would you want to do that?

Finally is there so it allways runs and does some finishing work which has to be done anyway, if ou want the code to be executed only when the try runs then write in in the try statement, otherwise if only when it fails then in the catch one. Code that has to tun in both cases has to be written in the finally section.

Answer (score 2):

The only way is to set a flag variable that your `finally` code tests, e.g.:

```
bool handled = false;
try
{
    throw new Exception("Try Error!!!");
}
catch(Exception exp)
{
    Console.WriteLine(exp.Message);
    Console.ReadLine();
    if (exp.Message == "Try Error!!!")
    {
        handled = true;
        return; // This isn't really necessary unless you have code below it you're not showing
    }
}
finally
{
    if (!handled)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Finally...");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

...but I'd really consider revisiting your logic so you don't need to do that. The *whole point* of `finally` is that no matter what happens within the `try` block, that `finally` code will run, whether you return early from the code in the `try` block, or an exception occurs, or you return from within the `catch` block.

Answer (score 2):

The whole point of finally is that it runs regardless of how the try/catch block executed. One workaround can be something like this:

```
    bool runfinallycode = true;
    try
    {
        throw new Exception("Try Error!!!");
    }
    catch(Exception exp)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(exp.Message);
        Console.ReadLine();
        if(exp.Message == "Try Error!!!")
            runfinallycode = false;
    }
    finally
    {
        if( runfinallycode )
        {
          Console.WriteLine("Finally...");
          Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally gets executed no matter what happens in the try catch block. It's meant that way so that you can free up resources before you exit the function.

Answer (score 1):

System.exit() can be used to avoid the execution of the finally block [Finally Block](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html). 
But if your condition is that the execution should not be hindered, then please do reframe the question.

Answer (score -1):

But your return is in a if clause so it will not always work. Try putting it outside the if in catch